# getting text content of specific element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get element text content only ignoring element's descendants, for instance if you look at this HTML:

```
<p>hello <h1> World </H1> </p>
```

for element "P" the right output should be ONLY "hello ".

I have checked the function: "element.textContent" but this returns the textual content of a node and its descendants (in my example it will return "hello world").

Thanks,

Comment: That would be the content of `h1`, not `p`.

Comment: Your markup is incorrect. `<h1>` element can't be inside `<p>`.

Comment: BTW your HTML code is broken, so most valid solutions posted below won't work. (you can't have block-level elements inside `<p />`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this HTML:

```
<div id="gettext">hello <p> not this </p> world?</div>
```

do you want to extract "hello" AND "world"? if yes, then:

```
var div = document.getElementById('gettext'), // get a reference to the element
    children = [].slice.call(div.childNodes), // get all the child nodes
                                              // and convert them to a real array  
    text = children.filter(function(node){
        return node.nodeType === 3;           // filter-out non-text nodes
    })
    .map(function( t ){ 
        return t.nodeValue;                   // convert nodes to strings 
    });    

console.log( text.join('') );                 // text is an array of strings.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7dcw/

Comment: You should also add a notice about browser support of `filter` and `map` methods.

Comment: IE9+ and every other sane browser. For IE8 and below you need to provide `Array.map` and `.filter` methods.

Comment: +1. This is the only answer here that *really* deserves the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

well behind it is an explanation

```
 $("p").clone()   //clone element
        .children() //get all child elements
        .remove()   //remove all child elements
        .end()  //get back to the parent
        .text();
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged `jQuery` so I wouldn't assume its presence ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer i have is the same provided in couple of other answer. However let me try and offer an explanation.

```
<p >hello<h1>World</h1> </p>
```

This line will be rendered as

hello

## World

If you look at this code it will be as follow

```
<p>hello</p>
<h1>World</h1> 
<p></p>
```

With the `<p>` tag you do not necessarily need the closing `</p>` tag if the paragraph is followed by a element.
[Check this article](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html)

Now you can select the content of the first p tag simply by using the following code

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
console.log(p[0].textContent);
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ssa9Y/)

Comment: Wrong. `textContent` returns ***all*** text content of a node, ***including*** the inner nodes.

Comment: @VisioN, have you checked the fiddle? or the explanation i have provided? im fecthing textContent of the first p node

Comment: @VisioN please stop trolling XD I just checked and it's returning just the hello String. Read MarsOne's Explanation and the Article, I understood it well after that

Comment: @BOTH The markup is incorrect. `<h1>` element can't be inside `<p>`. The browser tries to repair it pushing `<h1>` out of `<p>`. Replace `<p>` with `<div>` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Then say it, instead of just saying Wrong. The spirit of SO is to learn stuff, if you just say wrong even when you are right, when the output is clearly the right string, people gets confused

Comment: @aleation I have provided the reason why this approach is wrong.

Comment: I know, AFTER commenting on various answers saying just "Wrong, it will output everything"

Comment: @aleation Are you OK? Even if the markup was correct, the approach with `textContent` **is wrong** because *it returns all text content of a node, including the inner nodes*. What else do you want to know to make it clear?

Comment: @VisioN, seems to me like you are make baseless comments without checking the post... LOOK AT THE HTML MARKUP RENDERED... look at the first p tag . do you see any othere nodes inside it besides the text "hello".

Comment: @VisioN Are YOU ok? xD If you noticed, after you provided the explanation, I deleted my own answer as I realized it's wrong, it's you who can't accept some constructive criticism because of your ego, we are just saying that if you go around just saying "You are wrong" even when they are getting the correct output (in a wrong way) people get confused xD

Comment: Crazy `:D` I am not *just* saying "You are wrong". Where have you seen that? I guess all my comments are accompanied with clear explanation, innit?

Comment: @VisioN, you one downvote doesnt make a difference buddy, three other ppl have upvoted my answer so guess that spoils your party doesnt it. think about it. what did you really achieve after all this? food for thought?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `childNodes` property, i.e.:

```
var p = document.querySelector('p');
p.childNodes[0]; // => hello
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzMzL/)

Comment: how about `<p>hello <h1> World </H1> THIS? </p>` :)

Answer (score 0):

Plain texts are considered as nodes named `#text`. You can use `childNodes` property of element `p` and check the `nodeName` property of each item in it. You can iterate over them and select just `#text` nodes.

The function below loops over all element in document and prints just `#text` items

```
function myFunction()
{
    var txt="";
    var c=document.body.childNodes;
    for (i=0; i<c.length; i++)
    {
        if(c[i].nodeName == "#text")
            txt=txt + c[i].nodeName + "<br>";
    };
    return txt;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @VisioN said in comments, using `nodeType` is much more safer (for browser compatibility) and recommended.

Comment: Is `#text` browser consistent? I'd better go for `.nodeType === 3`.

Comment: Yes you'r right. It would be much better to use `nodeType` for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to

```
<p id="id1">hello <h1> World </h1> </p>
```

Use this script,

```
alert(document.getElementById("id1").firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide id for the element which you want to do some operation with that.

```
Below is the working example, it show output as "hello" as you expected.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showParagraph()
{
   alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="test">hello <h1> World </H1> </p>
<input type="button" onclick="showParagraph()" value="show paragraph" />
</body>

</html>
```